# JS random order showing divs delay issue

Tags: javascript

I got function within JS which is supposed to show random order divs on btn click.
However once the btn is clicked user got to wait for initial 10 seconds ( which is set by: setInterval(showQuotes, 10000) ) for divs to start showing in random order which is not ideal for me.

JS:

```
var todo = null;
var div_number;
var used_numbers;

function showrandomdivsevery10seconds() {
  div_number = 1; 
  used_numbers = new Array();

  if (todo == null) {
    todo = setInterval(showQuotes, 10000);
    $('#stop-showing-divs').css("display", "block");
  }
}

function showQuotes() {
  used_numbers.splice(0, used_numbers.length);
  $('.container').hide();
  for (var inc = 0; inc < div_number; inc++) {
    var random = get_random_number();
    $('.container:eq(' + random + ')').show();
  }
  $('.container').delay(9500).fadeOut(2000);
}

function get_random_number() {
  var number = randomFromTo(0, 100); 
  if ($.inArray(number, used_numbers) != -1) {
    return get_random_number();
  } else {
    used_numbers.push(number);
    return number;
  }
}

function randomFromTo(from, to) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}
```

**Question:** How to alter the code so upon the btn click divs will start showing right away without initial waiting for 10 seconds? (take in mind I want to keep any further delay of 10 seconds in between of each div being shown)

Thank you.

Comment: Just before `setInterval`, call `showQuotes()`.

Comment: Call showQuotes?

Comment: Call `showQuotes` instead of just deferring it to the interval?

Comment: I sense a trend.

Answer (score 0):

Call it when you begin the interval

`todo = setInterval((showQuotes(),showQuotes), 10000);`